# Pyrthon script to calculate two rows together from same column based on a match between same rows in two different columns

Tags: python, pandas, calculation

I want to create a Python script to calculate a new column, based on subtracting two values from same column in two different rows.

The two rows used for the calculation should be defined by being a match in values of two other columns. So, to specify and give an example:

| Id | Tag | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3.75 |
| 2 | xxx | 15 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | xxx | 14 |
| 5 | 6 | 5 |
| 6 | xxx | 15.5 |

The above table is an example of what I have right now.

The below table is including the column that I would like to create. For me, it does not matter if 'NaN or 0' is in the specified row or the row afterwards:

| Id | Tag | Amount | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3.75 | NaN or 0 or simply the value from Amount |
| 2 | xxx | 15 | 11.25 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | NaN or 0 or simply the value from Amount |
| 4 | xxx | 14 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 | 5 | NaN or 0 or simply the value from Amount |
| 6 | xxx | 15.5 | 10.5 |

So here, the value of NewColumn in the second row is equal to 11.25, because the following conditions are met:

- The value of the column 'Id' is equal to the value in the column 'Tag'.
- Therefore, the NewColumn should take the value of the column 'Amount' in row the bigger number and subtract it by the value in the row with the smaller number.
- This means that the calculation is 15-3.75 = 11.25.

To give some context, the value in 'Amount' in row 2 is with VAT included. The value in the row before of the same column is the VAT by itself. The Id is the Transaction ID, and the Tag column are used to link together the VAT transaction the correct corresponding full transaction.

I have tried to use ChatGPT to solve this issue, but can not seem to fully solve it. Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataset into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/dataset.csv')

# Define the name of the column to fetch data from
other_column_name = 'other_column_name'

# Iterate over each row in the dataframe
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Fetch data from another row and column based on an exact match
    search_value = row['column_name']
    matching_row = df.loc[df['column_name'] == search_value]
    if len(matching_row) == 1:
        other_column_data = matching_row[other_column_name].values[0]
    else:
        other_column_data = None

    # Use the fetched data to calculate a new column
    if other_column_data is not None:
        new_column_data = row['existing_column'] + other_column_data
    else:
        new_column_data = None

    # Add the new column to the dataframe
    if new_column_data is not None:
        df.at[index, 'new_column'] = new_column_data

# Save the updated dataset to a new CSV file
df.to_csv('path/to/new_dataset.csv', index=False)
```

Which simply outputs a combination of the values in Tag and Id.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can use pandas' groupby and shift functions to achieve your goal

Comment: I would like to know how the Python script should look, to be able to create the new column based on the conditions. I can see that the second table is not really viewable, but I am currently unable to edit due to too many edits on Stackoverflow. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: magedo - Thank you. I will try and look at the shift and groupby function together. Have only ever used groupby. If you have an idea of how the script could look, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `iterrows`, rather go for a vectorial approach:

```
# identify rows with "xxx"
m = df['Tag'].ne('xxx')

# set up grouper for Tag and successive xxx
g = df.groupby(m.cumsum())['Amount'].transform

# assign difference on "xxx" rows
df.loc[~m, 'NewColumn'] = g('max')-g('min')
```

Output:

```
   Id  Tag  Amount  NewColumn
0   1    2    3.75        NaN
1   2  xxx   15.00      11.25
2   3    4    4.00        NaN
3   4  xxx   14.00      10.00
4   5    6    5.00        NaN
5   6  xxx   15.50      10.50
```

###### if the "xxx" are variable strings

```
# keep only numeric Tags
s = pd.to_numeric(df['Tag'], errors='coerce')

# set up grouper for Tag and successive ones
g = df.groupby(s.ffill())['Amount'].transform

# assign difference on non Tag rows
df.loc[s.isna(), 'NewColumn'] = g('max')-g('min')
```

Example:

```
   Id  Tag  Amount  NewColumn
0   1    2    3.75        NaN
1   2  abc   15.00      11.25
2   3    4    4.00        NaN
3   4  def   14.00      10.00
4   5    6    5.00        NaN
5   6  ghi   15.50      10.50
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mozway. However, I suppose this is not suitable if the values in the 'Tag' column is anything other than xxx? There will be a few different tags such as "deposit", "subscription" etc..

Comment: Yes of course, let me give you an example. So you have either number or strings?

Comment: See update, you might want to update your question with a representative example

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thanks a lot. It seems to have worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was close to the truth:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'Tag': [2, 'xxx', 4, 'xxx', 6, 'xxx'],
                   'Amount': [3.75, 15, 4, 14, 5, 15.5]})

# create empty column for new values
df['NewColumn'] = None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if isinstance(row['Tag'], int):
        matching_row = df.loc[df['Id'] == row['Tag']]
        if not matching_row.empty:
            new_value = matching_row.iloc[0]['Amount'] - row['Amount']
            df.at[index, 'NewColumn'] = new_value

df['NewColumn'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

returns

```
   Id  Tag  Amount  NewColumn
0   1    2    3.75      11.25
1   2  xxx   15.00       0.00
2   3    4    4.00      10.00
3   4  xxx   14.00       0.00
4   5    6    5.00      10.50
5   6  xxx   15.50       0.00
```

**EDIT**

IF you get all values to 0 in the last column, this means that `ID` is a string. So, I suggest that you convert them to `Int` before applying the method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'Tag': [2, 'xxx', 4, 'xxx', 6, 'xxx'],
                   'Amount': [3.75, 15, 4, 14, 5, 15.5]})
df['Id'] = df['Id'].astype(int)
print(df.info())
# create empty column for new values
df['NewColumn'] = None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if isinstance(row['Tag'], int):
        matching_row = df.loc[df['Id'] == row['Tag']]
        if not matching_row.empty:
            new_value = matching_row.iloc[0]['Amount'] - row['Amount']
            df.at[index, 'NewColumn'] = new_value

df['NewColumn'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df.info())
```

which gives you what you expected. You can of course convert them back to strings afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot Serge! It is in fact working with the provided test dataset. However, when I use it with my own dataset, I simply get 0 for all rows in the new column. 

I have made sure the datatypes are the same for Id and Tag - they are strings. Should that be an issue? 

Otherwise, do you have any idea what could cause this issue? The dataset is quite large with many columns, but let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: @MaxP Yes, it matters. I edited my answer

Comment: The problem is that the xxx values represent text inserts as well - such as "subscription" - "one-time-payment" etc. I suppose I could make all of these integers in a way, but that would lose a lot of the information. Is there any way to do this without converting them to integers?

Comment: @MaxP Then I think mozway answer below is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am unable to edit my question, I would like to contribute with this update to make my second table readable.

| Id | Tag | Amount | NewColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3.75 | NaN or 0 or simply the value from Amount |
| 2 | xxx | 15 | 11.25 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | NaN or 0 or simply the value from Amount |
| 4 | xxx | 14 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 | 5 | NaN or 0 or simply the value from Amount |
| 6 | xxx | 15.5 | 10.5 |

I should also add, that I can not simply apply a singular VAT percent rate for these transactions, as the transactions differ in their VAT.

Also, it is not to be expected a "perfect" relationship here where the corresponding rows will be right after each other.